# How to pass DataTable or any collection to cshtml view in asp mvc without Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have been struggling with this for a while, trying to pass either `DataTable` or `EnumerableRowCollection` from my model through controller and display in a view. But no matter what I do I always get `nullPointerException`.

I've tested passing single string and it works, so I know I am passing my model to cshtml view.

Model class:

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        String test = "test";

        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("inside");
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbCon"].ConnectionString;
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = constr;
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("getProductInfo", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            sda.Fill(dt);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("fail !");
        }

        EnumerableRowCollection<UInt32> productIds = from productId in dt.AsEnumerable() select productId.Field<UInt32>("productId");

        foreach (int productId in productIds)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("id  " + productId + " number of rows " + dt.Rows.Count);
        }

        EnumerableRowCollection<String> vendorProductIds = from vendorProductId in dt.AsEnumerable() select vendorProductId.Field<string>("vendorProductId");
        EnumerableRowCollection<String> productNames = from productName in dt.AsEnumerable() select productName.Field<string>("productName");
    }

    public string test { get; set; }
    public DataTable dt { get; set; }
    public EnumerableRowCollection<UInt32> productIds { get; set; }
    public EnumerableRowCollection<String> vendorProductIds { get; set; }
    public EnumerableRowCollection<String> productNames { get; set; }
}
```

Controller with latest attempt at using Viewbag  (still same nullpointer)

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Product p = new Product();
        ViewBag.dt = p.dt;
        return View(p);
    }
```

Latest iteration of view with viewbag

```
<tbody>
@for(int i=0; i< ViewBag.dt.Rows.Count; i++) {
    <tr class="odd gradeX">
        <td>@Html.(ViewBag.dt.Rows[i]["productId"].ToString())</td>
        <td>@Html.(ViewBag.dt.Rows[i]["vendorProductId"].ToString())</td>
        <td>@Html.(ViewBag.dt.Rows[i]["productName"].ToString())</td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
```

Crashes on `@for(int i=0; i< ViewBag.dt.Rows.Count; i++) {`

I've tried using `Modal.dt.xx.xx`  and other lambda expressions and all of them end in same way...  I must be missing something

Comment: I think you should rethink what you are trying to do. MVC pushes for a pattern where domain objects are retrieved from a data store, mapped into POCO model classes and then used to render views. If you aren't using this pattern then you are trying to force mvc to do something that it isn't meant to do. Transform your data table in a List of Product objects, or better yet, use an ORM. There's a reason why no one uses data tables anymore, it makes code harder to read, harder to test and harder to maintain.

Comment: @NickBailey I said any collection  not only dataTable ( and if you look I have separate  fields for rows as  enumerables), how is this related to mvc in any way, I am getting data With  Model from database, using controller to pass it to view to display, exactly what mvc is.. only thing I dont want to do is  use full on entity framework..

Comment: A fair point. I think the thing that's key to ASP.NET MVC (as distinct from the pattern more generally) is the idea of a 1-1 explicit relationship between the model backing your view (not necessarily the domain model) and the view itself. 
I think my big suggestion here is use a poco class for your model rather than rows out of a data table or EnumerableRowCollection, and use a wrapper class containing a collection of that class as the strongly typed model on your view. That way you aren't relying on the dynamically typed ViewBag, and other developers will be able to reason about your code.

Comment: That said, I think the issue is that @Html.(expession) should just be @expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `dt` in the `Product` constructor, which is filled by the database, is different from the Product's property `dt`, which is filled to the viewbag in the controller, because you've overridden it in the constructor's first line. From the top of my head, that could be the reason of the nullPointerException.

You can replace the first line of the constructor by:

```
this.dt = new DataTable();
```

or you could replace a shorthand definition of the property `dt` by a full definition, and use the corresponding private field (e.g., `_dt`) in the constructor.

Comment: that actually  was the  issue, but it puzzles me why,  its not like I am  passing DataTable into my constructor, I removed viewbag declaration  and able to use it directly from Model (as I was trying to  originally )